# CSS: Different css code to ul tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
 .sf-menu li:hover ul{
    left:           0;
    top:            34px; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index:        99;
    width:auto;
height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
 -moz-column-width: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: auto;
  column-width: auto;

}
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left:           0;
    top:            34px; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index:        99;
    width:auto;
height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
 -moz-column-width: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: auto;
  column-width: auto;   
}
```

so in the correspondent html, the tag `<ul>` is getting this css settings right, is it possible to use a tag like `<ul2>` and change the css for the part of the list using this tag? I'm lost here, can you do that to the `<ul>` tag?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code too please, so we can get the full story? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a tag like `<ul2>` will not give you the expected results. The standard way to handle something like this is CSS classes.

Your tag in the HTML would be

```
<ul class="second-ul">
```

and then you could declare a specific style withL

```
ul.second-ul {
    /*Put your style definition here*/
}
```

Comment: so id be something like, .sf-menu li:hover ul.second-ul {} and then <ul class="second-ul"> ???